# 4 primary partition problem

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I am trying to install Ubuntu 15.04 on my Windows 7 HP pavilion g6. Since it already has 4 partitions even if a create a new unallocated partition the Ubuntu installer shows it as "unusable".
The 4 partitions are as follows

```
1 system 
2 (c:)
3 recovery 
4 hp_tools
```

How can I add and use an extra partition?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem on my Asus notebook. Asus offered tools to store the recovery information on an external hard drive (or a DVD), such that I could safely delete the recovery partition. 
Maybe HP has something similar?

Edit: it's written down in the how-to's concerning recovery on the [support site](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC-series/5048672/model/5078477/how-to).

Comment: Link didn't work...  ;-)

Comment: by mistake I had pasted the link to the article, not the overview. It's corrected now.